# reading data with gfortran

Tags: arrays, gfortran

I would like to read a data array in a fortran code with this line: `read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, (datbinsa(ibin), & ibin= 1, nbins), (datbinsb(ibin), ibin= 1, nbins)`

I am compiling with gfortran. Unfortunately, this error message appears: `read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, (datbinsa(ibin), & 1 Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)`

I can read the lines if I put only: `read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, datbinsa(ibin)` But I would like to read the whole array! How can I read an array when usin ggfortran as compiler? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the statement continuation symbol in free source form Fortran files. It should be the last non-blank symbol on the line and the statement continues on the next line:

```
 read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, (datbinsa(ibin), &
      ibin= 1, nbins), (datbinsb(ibin), ibin= 1, nbins)
```

If you join the two lines together, you should remove the `&`. But then you must also observe the maximum line length, which is 132 characters in the free source form.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There were two problems: one was that I should put in 1 line. The second one was to change the array reading like this: read(irdcld, 9101,end=9000) ctest, lay, frac, datbinsa(1:nbins),datbinsb(1:nbins)

Comment: `datbinsa(1:nbins)` and `(datbinsa(ibin), ibin=1,nbins)` should work the same in this case. The latter form is called an implied do loop and is much used in older Fortran code, before vector operations were introduced in the language.

Comment: unfortunately (datbinsa(ibin), ibin=1,nbins) does not work, as it seems gfortran does not lik ethe "(" sign. It puts the error message "Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)" at the "(" sign. This is my question why??

Comment: @user1809699, what is the extension of the source file? `.f`, `.f90`, `.F`, something else?